# how dual vector spaces are different form dual graph concept

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

For a vector space, $V$ dual vector space $V^*$ is the collection of 1-forms, while dual graph G is a graph that has a vertex for each face of G and so on...

My question is, intuitively there exist a $1$-$1$ correspondence in dual graphs, but I am unable to have such intuitive correspondence for dual vector spaces.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the 1 to 1 correspondonce on graphs you are talking about and why it is important for your question? Your comparison to graph duality seems confusing to me. Duality is a very general concept in maths and not restricted to graphs and vector spaces.

Comment: Actually, for graphs, like Delaunay triangulation and Voronoi are duals in the sense that for each face in Delaunay we have a corresponding vertex in Voronoi this is sort of 1-1 correspondence I am talking about. however in vector spaces such idea that a vector in $V$ corresponds to a 0-form in $V^*$ seems inappropriate...

Comment: Why does it look inappropriate to you? Is it because you map vectors to 1-forms and it seems the latter ones are of a completely different kind than the vectors? This corresponds to the mapping of a vertex to a face, both are of different kind too. Try to explain what looks so strange to you, otherwise any explanation might miss the point.